# Looking for title & author. Earth has a gateway device for interstellar travel

Tags: story-identification, aliens

...and an alien race has FTL space travel. We want access to their list of habitable planets, they want the secret to our gateway. Protagonist is a man created by the alien race, but does not know it. Falls in love with a woman that he shouldn't. Realizes he doesn't have memories of growing up.  Can't say when I read it (more than 20 years).

Comment: Are the aliens humanoid? Is their idea of "habitable planet" the same as ours?

Comment: I assume you know the protagonist does _not_ know he's created by the alien race, since he later realizes he doesn't have memories of growing up?

Comment: @tobiasvl I assume you mean "I assume you mean..."

Comment: @rojomoke Hehe, yes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heechee is the closest thing I could find, but it's sort of the reverse.

Comment: @rallen, thank you very much. That is it exactly. Should've remembered it was Foster. Even in my foggy memory I can hear is his style. I love this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[The I Inside](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35155.The_I_Inside)* by Alan Dean Foster.

[image: The I Inside by Alan Dean Foster]

Published 1984. I read it when I was a young boy. The main character is a sort of bioengineered alien human hybrid, who has most of the abilities the aliens have but looks human. His name is Eric Abott.

He has a sudden glimpse of a woman in a car, and becomes obsessed with her. She falls in love with him too, but for various political reasons, they're not allowed to be together. They decide to escape to be together in a colony on the other side of the gate.

The aliens have a list of habitable planets from various automated probes, but they can't actually get to the planets without the gate.
Eric is meant to be a deep sleeper agent who gets access to the gate, but the aliens fail to make him properly, and he ends up far more human than he should have been.